# Are deleted questions taken into account in the overall amount of questions asked?

Tags: support, questions, statistics

Just out of curiosity, In the picture below, are deleted/migrated/soft deleted questions counted toward this number?

[image: Your eyes are immediately drawn to the ugly red oval around the question count]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, deleted questions are removed from that count the next time the count updates (usually very soon after). It's just not very noticeable that the count decreases on larger sites because the intake of new questions kind of covers it up.

Just because a question gets closed doesn't remove it. Only deleted questions are excluded from the count (migrated questions get automatically deleted).

Comment: is that true for soft-deleted questions as well? (questions that aren't technically deleted, but aren't visible below 10k - or whatever the threshold is, i'm not sure :P)

Comment: All questions are soft deleted. It's very rare that a question is ever hard deleted. Only the devs can do that.

Comment: Ah ok, that makes sense, thanks